# Why do I get an error when running control center in a confluent cluster environment?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-control-center

my environment is centos 7 and Cluster (The number of brokers is 3)

error below :

```
[2023-06-08 11:22:49,034] ERROR [main] found topic=_confluent-command with replication=1 expecting at least expectedReplication=3 (io.confluent.controlcenter.KafkaHelper)
[2023-06-08 11:22:49,034] ERROR [main] found topic=_confluent-command with isr=1 below minIsr=2 (io.confluent.controlcenter.KafkaHelper)
[2023-06-08 11:22:49,034] ERROR [main] Startup failed to create necessary topics (io.confluent.controlcenter.KafkaHelper)
```

control center config :

```
confluent.controlcenter.internal.topics.replication=3
confluent.controlcenter.internal.topics.partitions=12

confluent.controlcenter.command.topic.replication=3
confluent.controlcenter.command.topic=_confluent-command

confluent.controlcenter.ui.autoupdate.enable=true
confluent.controlcenter.usage.data.collection.enable=true
confluent.controlcenter.ui.controller.chart.enable=true

confluent.monitoring.interceptor.topic=_confluent-monitoring
confluent.monitoring.interceptor.topic.partitions=12
confluent.monitoring.interceptor.topic.replication=3

confluent.metrics.topic.partitions=12
confluent.metrics.topic.replication=3
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the command topic could not be created automatically. It was already found with less replicas. Perhaps you or someone else is also running Control Center for your cluster? If so, use that, or otherwise delete the old topic(s).

Note: The default replication factor for each of those topics is already 3, so you don't need to explicitly set those.

Also, CentOS 7 is deprecated, and [may no longer be supported](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#operating-systems)